How to return plain text or JSON depending on condition?
Is there a way to do something like this using FastAPI:
@app.post("/instance/new", tags=["instance"])
async def MyFunction(condition):
    if condition:
        response = {"key": "value"}
        return response
    else:
        return some_big_plain_text

The way it is coded now, the JSON is returned fine, but some_big_plain_text is not human friendly. If I do: @app.post("/instance/new", tags=["instance"], PlainTextResponse) I get an error when returning a JSON response.

why not wrap the plain text into a json? {"response" : some_big_plein_text}

Have a look at this answer (along with this), in order to better understand what takes place behind the scenes, when returning a response from a FastAPI endpoint, as well as how to return a custom Response directly.

It is just needed to add a FastAPI Response:
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response

@app.post("/instance/new", tags=["instance"])
async def MyFunction(condition):
    if condition:
        response = {"key": "value"}
        return response
    else:
        return Response(content=some_big_plain_text, media_type="text/plain")

